# command conflicts in /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I update gnu screen with homebrew which located in `/usr/local/bin/screen`, it conflicts with `/usr/bin/screen`.

I can't write `/usr/bin` with `sudo` after update to `OS X EI Capitan`.
What should I do to use `/usr/local/bin/screen` as default?

Comment: Put /usr/local/bin first in PATH

Comment: @stark thanks very much! that works !

Answer (score 0):

Your shell uses the first command it finds using your `PATH`. The easy solution is thus to move `/usr/local/bin` first in your `PATH` so it’s *before* `/usr/bin`. This means that *all* commands in `/usr/local/bin` will be taken before those with the same name in `/usr/bin`.